# Check if input text with same id have same value

Tags: jquery, forms, input

I have a form with multiple input type texts with the same id.
So i want to check through JQuery on submit if any of these inputs have the same value.
Is that possible? If so, please help.
**Note:** Forget about same id. Let's say each have a different id. How to check then?

Comment: IDs must be unique.

Comment: why have you given same ids to all the inputs? this is wrong!!

Comment: Move your IDs to class or data-id

Comment: I can change the ids, so what to do then?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the general process you could follow

1. Enumerate all fields which you like to compare
2. Increment a counter for the value of the field
3. When you reach the end, check if any items have a count > 1

For example, this code does what you want:

```
$('#check').click(function(){
    var idx = {};
    $('.unique').each(function(){
         var val = $(this).val();
        if(val.length)
        {
            if(idx[val]){
                idx[val]++;
            }
            else{
              idx[val] = 1;   
            }
        }
    });
    var gt_one = $.map(idx,function(e,i){return e>1 ? e: null});
    var isUnique = gt_one.length==0
    alert(isUnique); //  Do something useful
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/6VfET/

Comment: Ok thanks, do you know a way in jquery to return how many text inputs i have? because the the form is dynamic.